# jQuery fadeIn div after page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i have a form that stores user data via an ajax call.

On success i normally have a div fade in with a success message. However i want to reload the page so that the page is updated, and then fade in the success message.

I was using a .load() to update the div, and then toggle the form to hide itself etc. But the .load was causing some other js scripts to not work after it was called etc so for now im going to just reload the page.

However, i want to show the success message div after the page has been reloaded.

This is an example:

```
    if (check) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process/updateuserpref.php",
    data: $('.updatepref').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){

    if (response.updatePrefSuccess) {
        location.reload();
        $('#successdisplay').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#successdisplay').delay(2500).fadeOut(400);
    }

    }
    });
    }
```

I know obviously the

```
     $('#successdisplay').fadeIn(1000);
     $('#successdisplay').delay(2500).fadeOut(400);
```

Doesnt currently work, but any help on how i can do what i want?

Thanks, Craig.

Comment: once you do `location.reload();` you're screwed. You're either in an endless loop of reloads, or if the above code is triggered by an event, all is lost, and no fading will happen today.

Comment: Use event delegation for your `other js scripts` or re-initialize them after loading the AJAX content. It will be a useful exercise in learning about asynchronous code. The issue is most likely that those scripts bound to elements that no longer exist when you update the HTML.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah I'd recommend not using `window.location.reload()` but instead changing the location to something similar with a query-string parameter to designate that something needs to happen (like fade-in an element).

Comment: @jasper Thanks for the reply, is it a common thing to happen then when using the load function that other scripts can be affected? I would love to use .load but this has been putting me off. I look into event delegation and asynchronous code :)

Comment: The issue isn't really with load(), it's the fact that you're replacing part of the DOM, inserting new elements, and the event handlers is only attached to elements that exists when the event handler is bound.

Comment: Why don't you update your page in the success function using the data from your php script? In this case you do not have to reload the page

Comment: It's an issue with replacing HTML, you can get the same effect with HTML generated client-side rather than using an AJAX request to get the HTML. The JS event handlers are bound to the specific HTML elements you're removing. So you need to bind to the new elements or use event delegation to actually bind to an ancestor element that always exists in the DOM (hence its event handlers won't be removed).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simple reloading you could sent a `GET` variable with the reload, then check if the GET variable exist show the success message if not, do nothing

I do the same thing, so this is how I do it:

intead of `reload()` I do:

> window.location.href = document.location.protocol +"//"+ document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname + '?success=1';

Then in my PHP script I do a conditional output:

```
<?php if( $isset( $_GET['success'] ) && $_GET[ 'success' ] == 1 )  { ?> 
    <div id="successdisplay">
        Changes performed Successfully
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: That looks like an interesting way to go about it.

Ill have a see tomorrow morning and try it out.